# Formatear número como moneda con expresión regular dinámicamente entregándole si lleva punto o coma y decimales

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

necesito formatear números dinámicamente como moneda, de forma dinámica (usando javascript o jquery), entregándole la cantidad de decimales, o si lleva punto o coma para separar sus miles.
Actualmente solo he podido hacer que me formatee con separador de miles, y ajustándole si lleva punto o coma, de esta manera:

```
let cant_decimales = 0;
let punto = ".";
let coma = ",";
let num = $("#input_numero").val();

num.replace(/(d)(?=(d{3})+(?!d))/g, "$1"+punto+"");
```

En lo anterior, por ejemplo si metiese un numero 1000, me devolvería un 1.000. Ahora me faltaría agregarle a la expresión regular, el como agregar decimales, en caso de que el número lo requiriera. Por ejemplo, si el número lleva 2 decimales, yo pudiera asignarlo a la variable cant_decimales, y meterla dentro de mi expresión regular para que la agregue o valide y me devolviese 1.000,00

Espero puedan orientarme si existe alguna mejor forma de hacerlo o como mejorar mi expresión regular para realizar lo que necesito.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

No se si esto es para un ejercicio donde verdaderamente lo que quiere el profesor es poner a prueba el conocimiento sobre expresiones regulares.

En caso de que puedas resolver el problema sin tener que usar obligatoriamente expresiones regulares y no quisieras reinventar la rueda, lo podrías solucionar usando la función `toLocaleString` del objeto primitivo `Number`

```js
let num = 123456.789;
console.log(num.toLocaleString('es-ES', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }));
console.log(num.toLocaleString('en-US'));
```

Esta función, convierte el entero en un formato numérico o de moneda, según lo que especifiques como parámetros.

En el primer ejemplo se utiliza el formato español de moneda, siendo la moneda el Euro. Por lo que el resultado es 123.456,79 € (redondeo con dos decimales)

El segundo ejemplo se utiliza el formato americano de número por lo que el número resultante es 123,456.789 (sin redondeo)

Hay varias opciones que se pueden pasar como `minimumFractionDigits` y `maximumFractionDigits` para forzar el número de decimales en caso de que quieras que se comporte de forma diferente a la localización estándar de los determinados países.

Más info:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString
- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number